# Incomming E-Mail doesn't work for the second site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, document, incoming-email

I have the following constelation. 
1. Sharepoint Site called "site1" on Port 80
1. SharePoint Site called "SharePoint Site X" on Port 95

The E-Mail receiving feature (to send documents to lists) works perfectly on the site on port 80. It get the documents an save them into the correct list. So the incomming e-mail is right configured I think.

But the receiving emails doesn't work on "SharePoint Site X".

The Windows Firewall is turned off.
The domain is already the same. So I have the same domain for the email Adress like "[listname]@customer.com".

What can be the Problem? 
Is the problem the other Port? 
Can I resolve it with another way instead of moving the site as subsite from "site1"?
Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There yre two ways for the solution

1. Update to the Latest CU or at least June CU 2012.
2. Go to Central Administration > Application Management > Configure quotas and locks > on the Site Quota Information section >  set a limit (i.e: 5000 MB) on this setting:  “Limit site storage to a maximum of:”  > and then press “OK”.

After that it works for me.